# How to do animation using "three-gltf-loader" npm package

Tags: reactjs, three.js, gltf

I am building an application on react where I have to show a 3D model (glTF) with an animation.

I am using "three-gltf-loader" npm package and I am able to load the 3D model correctly. But while playing the animation it's not working fine. As soon as I add the code to initiate the animation the model is becoming distorted.

I tried searching the solution over google, but its not working out for me. I am using the basic code base from this URL "https://medium.com/@colesayershapiro/using-three-js-in-react-6cb71e87bdf4".

The following code is on the function "componentDidMount()"

```
    let clock = new THREE.Clock();
    const loader = new GLTFLoader();
    loader.load(
      objMap,
        ( gltf ) => {
            const model = gltf.scene;
            // called when the resource is loaded
            model.traverse( function ( child ) {
                if ( child.isMesh ) {
                    child.geometry.center(); // center here
                }
            });
            model.scale.set(100,100,100);


            if (gltf.animations && gltf.animations.length) {
              const mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(model);
              mixers.push( mixer );
              for (var i = 0; i < gltf.animations.length; i++) {
                  var animation = gltf.animations[3];
                  if (animation.name == 'Idle'){
                    mixer.clipAction(animation).play();
                  }
              }
            }

            scene.add( model );

        },
        ( xhr ) => {
            // called while loading is progressing
            console.log( `${( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 )}% loaded` );
        },
        ( error ) => {
            // called when loading has errors
            console.error( 'An error happened', error );
        },
    );
```

The following code is on the function "animate()"

```
    for ( let mixer of this.mixers ) {
      mixer.update( delta );
    }
```

...[image: Image for reference]

Comment: Can you please try it without centering the geometry?

Comment: @Mugen87 Yes it's working fine now. Thanks a lot. Also but I want this to be in center so how I will do that? With position?

Comment: Yes. Try it with this code: https://github.com/donmccurdy/three-gltf-viewer/blob/18f43073bbfdbd3c220e2059e548e74c507522d2/src/viewer.js#L219-L227. It is from a model viewer application but it should also work for your use case.